# When caching, turn view state off?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a page that returns search results (text and images). The page has two tabs, one loading the companies and the other products.

When I click on either tabs to load the results, it seems to take quite some time. I was considering caching the results. Will turning off the viewstate help improve the performance/load time?

Answer (score 0):

ViewState must be disabled because the hidden input field can store very large data that might bloat the page and can cause performance on post backs

Read this article the author gives good explanation http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2005/09/07/163107.aspx

I would advise you to do more investigation on how either of them suits your application